# Two forms interfere with each other on submit

Tags: php

I have two forms on a page-'indexpage plus a included page'. Their actions point as so action=''. The problem is when I hit submit on the search bar, it shows a header error. The submit for the login works fine. I narrowed the problem all the way down to

```
tabindex="6" type="submit"
```

in the submit button of the login form.

They both have different names.

Login Form:

```
echo'<div id="container"> 
  <div id="topnav" class="topnav"> <font color="white">Have an account? &nbsp</font> <a href="login" class="signin"><span>Sign in</span></a><a href="/*********/register" class="signin3"><span>Sign Up</span></a> </div>
  <fieldset id="signin_menu">';
  output_errors($errors);
  echo'
    <form id="signin" action="" method="POST" >
    <br>
      <label for="username"><font color="black">Username or email</font></label>
      <input id="username" name="username" value="" title="username" tabindex="4" type="text">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password"><font color="black">Password</font></label>
        <input id="password" name="password" value="" title="password" tabindex="5" type="password">
      </p>
      <p class="remember">
        <input id="signin_submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" tabindex="6" type="submit">
        <input id="remember" name="remember_me" value="1" tabindex="7" type="checkbox">
        <label for="remember"><font color="black">Remember me</font></label>
      </p>
      <p class="forgot"> <a href="/*********/recovery/password" id="resend_password_link">Forgot your password?</a> </p>
      <p class="forgot-username"> <A id=forgot_username_link 
title="If you remember your password, try logging in with your email" 
href="/recovery/username">Forgot your username?</A> </p>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>';
```

Search Form:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' value='". $clean ."' name='keywords'/> 
<input type='submit' name='submit2' Value='Search'/>
</form>
```

Header Error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\xampp\htdocs*********\index.php:298) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\xampp\htdocs*********\pages\search.inc.php on line 35

Answer (score 0):

I'm petty sure that error is due to you trying to output (echo/print) something before trying to redirect in the headers. Redirects `header('Location: /anotherpage.php');` after an echo or some printed HTML are probably the cause.

Comment: If i'm logged in and the form disappears, it works fine, but if the form is there it doesn't, and its caused by these two attributes tabindex="6" type="submit". If i take these out the search submit works, but the login form button is no longer functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my input for the login submit. Here is what I did.

I change this

```
<input id="signin_submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" tabindex="6" type="submit">
```

Too this

```
<input name="submit" value="Sign in" type="submit">
```

Apparently the tabindex and id had some kind of issue, not sure why.